# Customize catalina log path in logging.properties

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I want to use a environment variable in Tomcat 7 logging properties.

Here's the default,

`1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs`

What i want to do is

`1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${MY_ENV_VARIABLE}/logs`

What Tomcat does is create a folder called `${MY_ENV_VARIABLE}` in CATALINA_HOME\bin and writes the logs there. It doesn't read the path from the Environment variable.

Any ideas of how i can use environment variable in logging.properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are not environment variable but JVM properties. You can add them by the `"-Dproperty-name=property-value"` when you launch java.

Thus to do what you want, you could set (for linux but same idea in windows)

```
export CATALINA_OPTS=$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcatalina.log.path=$MY_ENV_VARIABLE
```

before launching tomcat and change your logging.properties file accordingly :

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.log.path}/logs
```

Comment: That would need to be ... = ${catalina.log.path}/logs in the final code snippet